# How to choose the version of gcc，kernel and glibc？

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

Hi，everyone！I want to know the choice of glibc, kernel, gcc version. For example, why does debian 9.4 choose the kernel of 4.9.0.7, gcc is 6.3.0, and glibc is 2.24. What is the relationship between the choices between versions? Can I choose gcc 4.9, glibc 2.0? Or gcc 4.9, glibc 2.1?

Comment: The kernel and library ABIs are very stable these days, so you can mix and match pretty freely.

Comment: If I want to build my own Linux system, just like LFS, but how does LFS know that gcc-8.2.0, glibc-2.28, linux-4.18.5 matching system is stable? As long as the relevant versions are compatible with each other? So even if I choose gcc5.1 and glibc-1.8, gcc6.3 and glibc-2.0 (randomly matched), as long as it works, it is ok?

Comment: Yes, if it builds and works it's typically fine. This is usually the case when the versions are only 1-2 years apart. If the releases are very far apart, they may no longer be compatible though, as with GCC 4.7 (from 2012) and glibc 2.28 (from 2018). In this case they'll just fail to build.

Comment: No magic here, but pay attention to any features you may want in your build tools, e.g. C11 - "Type-generic expressions" were not available in gcc until 4.9, etc.. Other than issues like that, you can pretty much roll your own combination but you would probably want to stay with kernel 4.4 or better, gcc 4.9 or better and glibc 2.1 or better. As a datapoint, the still supported openSuSE Leap 42.3 uses kernel 4.4, gcc 4.8.5 and glibc 2.22, at the other end Archlinux uses kernel 4.19.8, gcc 8.2.1 and glibc 2.28. Both will handle builds of anything needed.

Comment: Copy that！Thanks！